# Date parsing not failing with invalid format

Tags: java, date, parsing, date-format, simpledateformat

The below piece of code should throw a parsing exception as per my understanding but it does not. Looked at the documentation but couldn't figure it out.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd", Locale.US);
dateFormat.setLenient(false);
dateFormat.parse("20160821_$folder$");
```

Comment: If using Java 8, you can use a DateTimeFormatter which is strict and would throw an exception in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)) says:

> Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a date. The method may not use the entire text of the given string.

As long as it finds the match, it stops scanning further which seems to be the case here.

If you want strict checking, you can add `RegEx` mathing on top of this, to prevent such strings from getting parsed.

Comment: That explains it. I wonder why they are not using the lenient flag. But as this is documented this is not a bug.